# Creating directory/file name rules for .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I'd like to set up some rules in my .gitignore whereby any directory or file with a name containing "_nogit" will be ignored.

Examples:

- ../videos_nogit/...
- bigvideo_nogit.mp4
- assets/_nogit/bigvideos...

Thanks--

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a line in your `.gitignore` file that does not have slashes in it, then `git` treats it like a shell glob pattern. Thus, adding `*_nogit*` to your `.gitignore` will ignore all of those files.

See also the [`gitignore` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).